# c++ run .exe file with parameters

Tags: c++, exe

Im trying to run exe file with c++ with no luck

I tried this:

```
system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Counter-Strike Condition Zero 1.2 build 2771\\hl.exe");
```

How i can run hl.exe with parameters?

Thanks

Update:

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` im getting this error.

I tried `system("C:\\hl.exe");` and it works good.
I think problem is in whitespaces

Comment: What is the error you are getting because normally this is the correct way

Comment: im trying to run .exe file. im not getting nothing

Comment: You might have to quote the path, like this: `"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Counter-Strike Condition Zero 1.2 build 2771\\hl.exe\""`

Comment: The spaces in seems to be your issue. because it says `"'C:\Program' is not recognized"` rather than `"C:\Program Files (x86)"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run your executable with parameters by adding them to the end of hl.exe as you would on the command line.

```
system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Counter-Strike Condition Zero 1.2 build 2771\\hl.exe fullscreen");
```

where fullscreen is the parameter to run hl.exe with.

With spaces in the path you can put quotes around the string containing the executable path:

```
system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Counter-Strike Condition Zero 1.2 build 2771\\hl.exe\" fullscreen");
```

Comment: please see my udpated question

Comment: You just need to escape the whitespace.